# Comparison of two categories over a specific period of time

Tags: grammar, writing, comparison, numbers, academic-writing

Year:       2009 / 2019

Mobile use: 15% / 26%

Tablet use:  5% / 19%

what is the correct way to describe changes in two different years? I have tried to describe the changes in three different sentences, yet I am not sure if the grammar is correct, especially the use of present perfect.

1. The use of mobile phone for viewing purposes has increased by almost three-quarters to 26%, **and tablet use seeing an almost four-fold increase to 19%**.
2. The use of mobile phone for viewing purposes has increased by almost three-quarters to 26%, **and tablet use has increased by almost four-fold to 19%.**
3. The use of mobile phones and tablets for viewing purposes accounted for one-fifth in 2009 (15% and 5% respectively), and has more than doubled to 45% in 2019 (26% and 19%, respectively).
4. In particular, the use of mobile phones and tables which accounted for one-fifth in 2009 (15% and 5%, respectively), has more than doubled to 45% in 2019 (26% and 19%, respectively).

[image]

Comment: 1. "*... and tablet use **is** seeing an almost four-fold increase to 19%.*"

2. "*... and tablet use has increased almost four-fold to 19%.*" (no "**by**")

Comment: This: The use of mobile phone for viewing purposes has increased by almost three-quarters to 26%, is not accurate. You increase from one percentage to another.

Comment: @lambie do you mean from 15% to 26%? I should add the begining point of the percentage before the ending to which is 26%.

Comment: Yes, 15% to 26%. Three quarters means 3/4 of something.

Comment: 1. "... and tablet use is seeing an almost four-fold increase from 5% to 19%." 2. "... and tablet use has increased almost four-fold from 5% to 19%.